# iOS: how to render flash for iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, flash

we need to render flash for an iOS app. the app is for educational purpose. Say we have to make a quiz and videos in flash.  What is the best way to make it happen? are there any good framework that does that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real option is for running Flash on iOS is [Adobe AIR for iOS](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html) which will package your Flash swf into an iOS app.

Comment: Do you know if there is any open source project or frameworks that does that?

Comment: I don't think so. There isn't any real way to embed flash content inside your app. Your only option is to write in flash and convert the whole thing to iOS through Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to encode your videos into an iOS friendly format such as MPEG-4 or H.264 (.m4v, .mp4, and .mov).

.flv files are unreadable on iOS.